# How to access an OpenCV Vec3f Mat with .data?

Tags: c++, opencv

For imaging purposes, I have a Mat created as

```
Mat_<Vec3f> I
```

If this is a Vec3b Mat then I know how to use the .data method to access its elements.

```
I.data[j*I.step + i*3 + x], where x={0,1,2}, j is row and i is column
```

I tried to do the same with Vec3f, but all the below don't work (throws me error):

```
I.data[j*I.step + i*12 + x], where x={0,4,8}
I.data[j*I.step[0] + i*I.step[1]*3 + x], where x={0,4,8}
I.data[j*I.step[0] + i*I.step[1]*3 + x], where x={0,I.step[1],I.step[1]*2}
```

What is the correct way to do this? I am choosing to use .data in order to attain greater execution speed (compared to .at and .ptr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that I.data is a `uchar *`, so you are only retrieving one byte of your float.

You need something like

```
float component = ((float*)(I.data + I.step.p[0]*j))[i * 3 + x];  // where x = {0, 1, 2}
```

Ok, I just pinched that code from the OpenCV source for `at()` and adapted it to your situation.  If you need to access pixels randomly, as long as you disable the debug assertions in `at()` you are not going to beat it. If you are accessing pixels sequentially there are much more efficient ways: get a point to a row as per berak's answer and simply traverse each row.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I should have searched for an answer in the source code. Still this looks quite complex.

Answer (score 5):

just try to use the front door first ;)

```
Vec3f & pixel = I.at<Vec3f>(j,i); // row, col world
```

if you *really* need a pointer, at least use:

```
Vec3f *pv = I.ptr<Vec3f>(j); // ptr to row j
pv[3][2] = 17; // 4th pixel, red channel
```

in other words, avoid accessing the raw uchar* data whenever possible

Comment: Thanks. It seems using a ptr in Release mode is already very efficient. I have been trying to squeeze some performance in Debug mode, which now seems needless.